# Excel Find Specific Instances & Append to the End of URL String

Tags: excel

I have a column of 16,000 URLs. Some of the items end in "/" that represents "default.htm". I would like to do a Find and Replace but only on items that end with the "/".

For example:

The column may look like this:

```
/employeeresources/timeattendance/itas/  
/employeeresources/pmap/ninpmap/ucm643423.htm  
/employeeresources/dmap/srapmap/ucm643521.htm
```

But it needs to look like this:

```
/employeeresources/timeattendance/itas/default.htm  
/employeeresources/pmap/ninpmap/ucm643423.htm  
/employeeresources/dmap/srapmap/ucm643521.htm
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a combination of `IF` and `RIGHT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data is in column "A", then the following should work:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="/",CONCATENATE(A1,"default.htm"),A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in a helper column.

```
=IF(RIGHT(A2,1)="/",A2&"default.htm",A2)
```